# Найти натуральный ряд

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

Есть отсортированный `list` с целыми числами. Размер - от 4 до 5 элементов. Как определить, являются ли 4 числа, входящие в коллекцию натуральным рядом? Может есть, что-то лучше чем(какая-нибудь встроенная функция например):

```
if len(arr) > 4 and (int(arr[-1]) - int(arr[1]) == 3 or int(arr[3]) - int(arr[0]) == 3):
    return True
elif int(arr[3]) - int(arr[0]) == 3:
    return True
else:
    return False
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если список отсортирован по возрастанию, то можно сравнить его с `range()`:

```
In [1]: lst = [4,5,6,7,8]

In [2]: lst == list( range(min(lst), max(lst)+1) )
Out[2]: True
```

Answer (score 0):

Натуральный ряд - неограниченно продолжающийся ряд целых положительных чисел, расположенных в порядке их возрастания: 1,2,3,4,5.

```
def natural_series(x):
for i in range(4):
    if x[i] == x[i + 1] - 1:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```